# Reducing an ODE Using Differential Invariants found from the Symmetries of the ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

I am using the symmetries of an ODE to determine the differential invariants and using the differential invariants to reduce the order of the ODE and solve it.
The ODE is:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = w\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{2}{y}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2
$$

The differential invariants I have found (and which correspond with the solution given) are:
\begin{align}
r&=ye^{wt}\\
v&= \frac{1}{wy}+\frac{1}{y'}
\end{align}

The solution states that in terms of $r$ and $v$ the ODE reduces to:
$$
w\frac{dv}{dr}r + 1 = 0
$$

I want to understand how to get to this given solution.

In previous questions related to this problem, I would sub-in $y''$ and that would simplify my numerator significantly and I would proceed from there.

When I do that I get:
\begin{align}
D_x v & = -\left( \frac{y'}{wy^2}+\frac{2}{y'}+\frac{2}{y}\right)\\
&= - \left(\frac{y^2 +2wyy'+w^2y^2}{y'wy^2}\right)\\
D_xr &= wye^{wt} + y'e^{wt}\\
&=e^{wt}(wy+y')\\
\frac{dv}{dr} &= \left(\frac{-\left(y'+wy\right)^2}{y'wy^2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{e^{wt}(wy+y')}\right)\\
&= \frac{-\left(y'+wy\right)}{e^{wt}wy^2y'}\\
&= \frac{-(y'+wy)}{rwyy'}\\
rw\frac{dv}{dr} &= \frac{-(y'+ wy)}{yy'}\\
&= \frac{-1}{y}-\frac{w}{y'}\\
\end{align}

I could also write this as:
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dr}r &= -\frac{1}{wy}-\frac{1}{y'}\\
&= -v\\
\end{align}

I am not able to see how I can get the solution given in the paper I am looking at.

Comment: @aliashja' can you have a look?